# Image and Text is Displayed When an Image is clicked on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help in trying to get a website to respond in the following manner: I want to be able to click on the image, which will then display the image and some information next to that image. I have already implemented the part of displaying an image, but don't know how to display the text next to it.
Here is what I have so far:

```html
<div class="image center">
      <a href="images/123.jpg"><img src="images/123.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<p class="color names">123</p>
</div>
```

This basically just enlarges the image on the screen.

Comment: _I want to be able to click on the image, which will then display the image_ image is already displayed right ?

Comment: Can also you post your JS code?

Comment: Boostrap provides _collapsibles_ , which can be used for this functionality with images. Here is reference: [Bootstrap collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig A library is a tad overkill

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not need or use a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a text show up when clicking on the image you need to write a function for it.

I've made a very simple example here that makes a text appear when clicking on the image, and then disappear when you click on it again. You can modify the code for your needs.

HTML

```
<div class="image center">
  <a href="#" onClick="showStuff()">
    <img src="images/123.jpg" /></a>
    <p class="color names">123</p>
</div>
# Here's the part that shows/hides when you click the image
<div id="hidden" style="display: none"><p>Here's the hidden text</p> 
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function showStuff() {
  let hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
  if (hidden.style.display == "none") {
    hidden.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    hidden.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```